# Why validation for Decimal not work for ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Why validation for Decimal not work for ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages ?

Client side work, but after post data I get this server side validation message (ModelState.IsValid = false in my case).
The value '1.000000' is not valid for...

[image]

Model property:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(16, 6)")]
public decimal ValueFactor { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.ValueFactor" />
<span asp-validation-for="ValueFactor" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Comment: if i'm understood correctly you are asking text box is not accepting decimals?

Comment: @this.girish if it is text box then it will accept everything.

Comment: @Sargis, Please check the type of the generated html input control.

Comment: @this.girish yes, after post data I get this server side validation message, client side works.

Comment: @TanvirArjel input type is text, I get this from server side, ModelState.IsValid = false in my case.

Comment: Are you by chance not american? This is typical for issues related to language and a disparity between the locale the application is running under and what the browser or you are expecting. I.e. if the serve is running german unless you force english locale for the test, you may end up with decimal expecting a "," and not a ".". The browser can be set to expect a specific langauge and you may have a code issue here.

Comment: @TomTom It can be, due to browser show data with this "," , what can I do to solve this?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.I could validate successfully on server side.Could you share your whole model and View.Also could you share your Post method?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I found a solution, the thing is in the regional settings of my computer, where the decimal symbol is a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: The thing is in the regional settings of my computer, where the decimal symbol is a comma.]

I found a solution, the thing is in the regional settings of my computer, where the decimal symbol is a comma.
Server side wants dot for decimal separator, but my client side wants comma as you can see in picture, that's why there is inconsistency, for resolving this just you need to change Decimal symbol type as shown in picture.

Comment: This is a work-around, not a proper solution. Changing the decimal symbol for the actual OS might break some other program.

Answer (score 0):

**Column** attribute is **[Code First Data Annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations)**

For validation of decimal you need a combination of regex and range validations like below:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{6}$")]
[Range(0, 9999999999.999999)]
```

**RegularExpression** attribute above will accept ' any number of digits, follwed by dot(.) and then 6 digits'. So following numbers are accepted: 1.000000, 500000.000000 etx.

Range attribute accepts a number of type **decimal(16,6)** between 0 and 9999999999.999999

Comment: Did you get same error 'The value is not valid for ValueFactor' ?

Comment: Exactly I get same error, I can't understand why model.state think that number with dot (1.20 or 1.000000) is invalid for decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on server side.

```
public class PersonModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Decimal Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,100})$", ErrorMessage = "Valid Decimal number with maximum  decimal places.")]
    public string Expenses { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My model

```
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public Decimal Bonus { get; set; }
```

I created a view model.

```
    [Display(Name="Ek Ücret")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d+),(\d{2})$", ErrorMessage = "Tutar 0,00 - 9999999999,99 aralığında olmalıdır. ")]
    public string Bonus { get; set; }
```